# Convert CloudFormation Custom SNS Resource to AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform, aws-cli

I'm trying to convert a vendor supplied CloudFormation Stack over to Terraform.  There is an `AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource` for sending an SNS notification:

```
...
"RegistrationNotification": {
  "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": {"Ref" : "SnsTopicRegistration"},
    "Version": "1.0",
    "AccountID": {
      "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
    },
    "CloudTrailCreated": {
      "Ref": "EnableNewCloudTrail"
    },
    "IamRoleARN": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "iamRole",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
  }
}
...
```

My plan is to have a local-exec resource for `aws sns publish`.  However, are the CustomResource Properties sent as message-attributes or are they sent in the message body?

Here's what I've tried so far, but the I don't believe it is working.

```
message.txt:
{
  "AccountID":"111111111111",
  "CloudTrailCreated":"false",
  "IAMRoleArn":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/TestRole"
}

aws sns publish --target-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:test-topic" --message file://message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting up my own **SNS->SQS** pipeline, and overriding the vendor's SNS target, I was able to see the full message that CloudFormation generates:

```
message.txt: 
{
  "RequestType":"Create",
  "ServiceToken":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:999999999999:registration",
  "ResponseURL":"https://custom-resource-response-useast1.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A111111111111%3Astack/Vendor_App/f16ba060-f981-11e8%7CRegistrationNotification%7C754d1dbc-2cc9-4b5f-855a?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIBLSGNTMEXAMPLE&Expires=1544126938&Signature=UohvGFPBHWrCz%2BMxgVKHF1L%2FNe4%3D",
  "StackId":"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:111111111111:stack/Vendor_App/f16ba060-f981-11e8-9ecc",
  "RequestId":"754d1dbc-2cc9-4b5f-855a",
  "LogicalResourceId":"RegistrationNotification",
  "ResourceType":"AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource",
  "ResourceProperties":{
    "ServiceToken":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:999999999999:cs-cloudconnect-manager-registration",
    "AccountID":"111111111111",
    "Version":"1.0",
    "IamRoleARN":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/TestRole",
    "CloudTrailCreated":"false"
  }
}
```

The AWS CloudFormation [Custom Resource Request Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requests.html) documentation was helpful in understanding which fields are mandatory.

Ultimately, my plan to use a local-exec resource fell apart and I resorted to calling the CloudFormation Stack from Terraform:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "vendor-stack" {
  name = "Vendor-App-Stack"
  capabilities = [ "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM" ]
  parameters {
    RoleName="TestRole"
    EnableNewCloudTrail="false"
  }
  template_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/vendor-prod-templates/aws_cloudformation_v1.0.json"
}
```